# Sitecore User Group Brazil - December 20, 2017

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Date/Time EST: Tuesday, December 20, 2017, Starts at 4:00 PM

Date/Time UTC: Tuesday, December 20, 2017, Starts at 9:00 PM

RSVP: http://meetu.ps/3fzzFv

Join us @Florianopolis, Tuesday Dec 20th, for our next Brazil Sitecore User Group(SUGBR).

Presentations

- Sitecore deployments: understanding and minimizing risks (José Neto)
- Sitecore Commerce (Leonardo Cunha)

Comment: @Mark Cassidy, would you be able to change the User Group date? We had couple issues and we've rescheduled for Dec 20 instead

Comment: Done :-)    Should take effect in a couple of minutes